# Computational complexity of exact computation of the doubling dimension

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-complexity, computer-science, computational-geometry, persistent-homology

Given a finite metric space $X$, the *doubling constant* of $X$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that any ball of arbitrary radius $r$ can be covered by at most $k$ balls of radius $r/2$. The *doubling dimension* of $X$ is defined to be $\dim X = \log_2 k$.

Despite references to doubling dimension being replete among computer science paper abstracts, and especially within computational geometry and topology, it is mostly assumed that the doubling dimension is known *a priori*.

As far as *computation* of doubling dimension, in ["Local Doubling Dimension of Point Sets"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4822.pdf) there is the remark on page $3$:

> It is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard to calculate the doubling
> dimension of a metric [$8$] but it can be approximated within a constant factor [$9$, Sec. $9$].

In [[8]](https://web.archive.org/web/20240102083042/https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Erobi/papers/GK-NearlyDoubling-SIDMA13.pdf), however, the problem is explained thusly:

> Interestingly, the problem of computing the exact doubling
> dimension of a point set is NP-hard. (This result seems to be folklore.) Yet this fact
> has not deterred the development of algorithms that are based on the doubling dimension, partly because it can be approximated within a constant factor, and partly
> because many of these algorithms function without explicit knowledge of the doubling
> dimension—it appears only in the analysis.

**My question is:** Is the $\mathrm{NP}$-hardness of exact doubling dimension computation "folklore" because it is trivial, or because it is really hard to prove? If the former, does anyone know a proof? If the latter, what is the heuristic by which one concludes it is probably $\mathrm{NP}$-hard?

**Edit:** After further Googling, I discovered there is a presentation by the authors of [8] above, apparently titled "It is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard to determine the doubling dimension of a set S" given at [this link](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eadi/approx10-doubling.ppt), which unfortunately does not seem to work without some type of authorization.

Comment: You can find an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20181127125440/https://cs.nyu.edu/~adi/approx10-doubling.ppt) of the Powerpoint presentation from the Internet Archive.